# Jquery check and uncheck checkbox with a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I am trying to dynamically check and uncheck a box with jquery .

The ideal situation would be that if edit project file was clicked this would show the field to upload a new image `(edit_project_image)` was active ie not removed via either a click again on `(edit_project_image)` or a click on `(remove_edit_image)`. Also if there is a strikethough, which would me that the class `remove_project_image` would be added then the checkbox would also be checked.

The idea is if any of the above is true the the current active image needs to be removed.

Here is my jquery right now:

```
//show hide the file box to edit images
$('.edit_project_file').live('click',function() {
    $(this).parent().next().toggle();
    $(this).parent().removeClass("remove_project_image");
    return false;
});

//allow the user to remove the file box if they don't wish to edit an image
$('.remove_edit_image').live('click',function() {
   $(this).parent().hide();
   $(this).parent().removeClass("remove_project_image");
    return false;
});

//add strikethough when the user decides to delete an image
$('.remove_project_file').live('click',function() {
   $(this).parent().toggleClass("remove_project_image");
   $(this).parent().next().hide();
   return false;
});
```

Here is the Html Markup:

```
<ul class="imgPreview">
    <li>
        <a href="#" rel="../images/portfolio/project_images/manager_pimg3_7_1281126121.jpg">manager_pimg3_7_1281126121.jpg </a>
        <a href="#" class="edit_project_file"> <img src="images/edit.gif"/></a>  
        <a href="#" class="remove_project_file"> <img src="images/delete.gif"/></a>  
    </li>   
    <li class="edit_project_image">
        <input name="upload_project_images[]" type="file" />  
        <a href="#" class="remove_edit_image" border="0"> <img src="images/delete.gif" /></a>
    </li>  
    <li>
        <input name="edit_image[]" type="checkbox" value="manager_pimg3_7_1281126121.jpg" class="edit_image_checkbox"/>
    </li>  
</ul>
```

I believe the best situation would set a var that if true will set the value of the checkbox to true.
Things i've tried include:

```
    $('.remove_project_file').live('click',function() {
   $(this).parent().toggleClass("remove_project_image");
   $(this).parent().next().hide();
   if ($(this).parent().next(".edit_image_checkbox").is(":not(:checked)")){
    $('.edit_image_checkbox').attr('checked',true);
    }

    return false;
});
```

The this works in the sense that it checks all (the above is in a php loop) the checkboxes with the class of `.edit_image_checkbox` instead of just the one next to the class of the `remove_project_file` that was clicked. Also there is no uncheck when the link is checked again for this i tried `else {$('.edit_image_checkbox').attr('checked',true);}` this just confuses it as it says if it's not checked then check it but then if it's checked uncheck it.

Another idea i had was to use a variable and set it to true or false and if true the box is checked. I tried this like:

```
    var file_checkbox_checked = false;
if(file_checkbox_checked ==  true){
$('.edit_image_checkbox').attr('checked',true);
}
else{
$('.edit_image_checkbox').attr('checked',false);
}
```

Then added `file_checkbox_checked = true;` to each of the functions that should check the checkbox. This seemed to do nothing. I could set  `var file_checkbox_checked = true;` and that would check all the checkboxes another problem with this is there is no way to uncheck it.

I am still in the learning, brainstorming part of this part of the project so if you have any ideas they would be great.

Comment: "I think i'll have to do something like this" - did you actually try it yet? are you encountering any issues?

Comment: Yes I tried, and a played around with the bit of code quite a bit. The issues I had are 1) It would check all the boxes with the class .edit_image_checkbox. 2) i could toggle on the checkbox by using $('.edit_image_checkbox').attr('checked',true); but not know how to toggle it off. I know how annoying it is when people come to forms and groups and just want answers. Trust me I'm here to learn but just stugged with this for the past 6 hours!

Comment: You typically get more responses when you post the html output rather than the php loop.

Comment: Unless I misread, your original post does *not* have any information on what you actually tried, therefore anyone attempting to answer I'd assume would be confused with what's actually going on.

Comment: Try re-wording your entire question with the issues you've experienced thus far with your attempt, and you probably don't need the php snippet unless you're having server-side issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I understand your requirement correctly [when does programmers not :) ], when user clicks edit or remove image you add or remove `remove_project_image` class to the `li` containing edit/remove link. Now if the class `remove_project_image` is added to the `li` you want to check the checkbox otherwise clear it. The following snippet does this.

```
$('.remove_project_file').live('click',function() {
    $(this).parent().toggleClass("remove_project_image");
    //TO KNOW IF STRIKE-THROUGH IS APPLIED TO IT OR NOT
    var r = $(this).parent().hasClass("remove_project_image");
    $(this).parent().next().hide();

    //WE NEED TO GET THE LI CONTAINING CHECK BOX, ONE NEXT TO HIDDEN ONE
    var t = $(this).parent().next().next();
    //GET CHECKBOX
    var c=$(".edit_image_checkbox", t);
    $(c).attr('checked',r);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much, if I i could I would by you a cookie :). This only answered half my question also needed it so if the edit_project_file was clicked (meaning if edit_project_image/$(this).parent().next() was shown) to also check the box. I modified your above function and pasted it into the .edit_project_file jquery making it `//TO KNOW IF THE EDIT BOX IS SHOWN OR NOT var r = $(this).parent().next().is(':visible');` Then used the rest of your code. Thanks again!

Comment: One last thing how would I uncheck the box on click of `.remove_edit_image` ?

Comment: Never mind, got it with, `var t = $(this).parent().next();` just had to remove one of the next() because we are getting the next element not the next() next() one.